# Google Maps working in browser running windows server, but not on Ubuntu server

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-maps, cordova, ubuntu, ionic3

Ionic 3 - Google Maps working in browser running windows server , but not on ubuntu server.

Using : 
`ionic cordova build browser`

I got browser build in ./platforms/browser/www

I moved this to /var/www/ which is document root for my apache web server running on aws ec2 ubuntu instance. Here, on this server I am not able to see google maps as shown below in Image 1

[image: Image 1]

But it is working fine when I run this on windows server under xampp as shown below in Image 2

[image: Image 2]

I have ran 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar'
Still Console error shows:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Badge
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Device
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for SplashScreen
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for StatusBar
StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
```

All Console errors :

```
HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Badge
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Device
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for SplashScreen
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for StatusBar

StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

/config.xml:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova.js:865 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found

fail @ cordova.js:865
SplashScreenProxy.js:163 [Browser][cordova.js][xhrStatusChangeHandler] Could not XHR config.xml: Not Found

(anonymous) @ SplashScreenProxy.js:163
core.js:3688 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
home.ts:31 Observable
home.ts:32 Observable

bootstrap.js:10 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1112 ms
BX-PPTG-BJP_Calzone_WoodBoard.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

PR_Sausage_Pepperoni_Woodboard.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BJP_FL_Cheesing.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Full-House-044-copy.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Good-Deal-002-copy.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Chicken-Med-010-copy.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Santa-Fe-052.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Natural-049-copy.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
BJP_FL_Jackpot.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BJP_FL_BBQ_Square-1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
BJP_Greek-Salad-CO-copy.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Salad-Spinach_Cherry.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Antipasto-Salad-Bowl.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
BJP_Southwest_Salad-Dressing.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BJP_PR_Chicken_Caesar_Salad.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Garden-Salad.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BJP_FL_Mediterranean_Salad.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
BJPCheeseBread.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BonelessWings_Hot.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
BJP_FL_Wings.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
AllBrands_CinnamonSticks.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

BlueBellIceCream.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
soda.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

StatusBarProxy.js:23 StatusBar is not supported
logo.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

polyfills.js:2 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.  
n @ polyfills.js:2
geolocation-map.ts:663 PositionError
```

Please let me know what is missing as I am very new to Ionic.

Comment: If you look at the console, are there any errors?

Comment: This page was loaded non-securely in an incognito mode browser. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see  
core.js:3688 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Badge
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for Device
cordova.js:1023 adding proxy for SplashScreen
HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the

Comment: server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.js:10 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1586 ms
HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
screen:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: util.js:44 Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.
pluginWarn @ util.js:44
util.js:56 Install the StatusBar  plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar'
pluginWarn @ util.js:56
polyfills.js:2 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.  
n @ polyfills.js:2

Comment: These are the console errors

Comment: ran this "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar"

Comment: Now only this error are remaining : This page was loaded non-securely in an incognito mode browser. A warning has been added to the URL bar.  
index.html:32 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/build/main.css 0 ()
index.html:21 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/cordova.js 0 ()
index.html:41 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/build/polyfills.js 0 ()
index.html:45 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/build/vendor.js 0 ()
index.html:48 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/build/main.js 0 ()
assets/icon/favicon.ico:1 GET http://x.x.x.x:8000/assets/icon/favicon.ico 0 ()

Comment: Can you edit the issue to make it clearer what’s going on, it’s very hard to read in comments

Comment: @ThomasEdwards update console error in main question hope is it's clear now

Comment: Wow, you have a lot of errors. It’s highly unlikely that it’s Google Maps breaking, but instead it’s just not even loading it due to JavaScript failing at some point. Try fixing your errors first, then come back.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards but same runs fine on windows machine please refer image 2 in my question

Comment: Do you get that many errors on the server? Image 2 appears to be a web server, not a local server.